# ‘Andersen’ and 'Anderson' – related?

Tags: word-difference, etymology

"Andersen" is the surname of the famous Danish fairy tale writer, Hans Christian Andersen.

"Anderson" is a common surname in Anglophone countries.

Do they have the same root?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with English, but in Scandinavian naming convention, the son or daughter was named with the father's or mother's name (patronymic or matronymic) followed by "son" (or "sen") or more rarely "dotter."  Thus, a fellow born to a man named **Anders** might be named _Torger Anders**son**_. The custom is still followed in some of Scandinavia, particularly in Iceland. (A former Prime Minister of Iceland was _Jóhanna Sigurðardóttir_; her father was named _Sigurd_.) Many English names have Scandinavian roots, tracing back to the _Danelaw_.

Comment: It has everything to do with English, since the surnames are used in  English.  It might be off-topic here, since questions about etymology and historical English are off topic, and perhaps questions about borrowed words and anglicizing words  too.  It seems ELU might be a better place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the history of English compared to related languages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the difference in two proper (family) names and their etymology, and is not about learning English.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Perhaps, but if I was learning German, one could ask exactly the same question on German SE. As far as the names are concerned, would that make it a German learning question?

Comment: @AlanCarmack We might as well ask here about the derivation of the names _Obama_ and _Khan._ While the U.S. president uses the former surname, and the mayor of London the latter, and they both appear frequently in English-language journals, the surnames are not English words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both mean the same thing, but have come to be spelt differently as the languages they are used in evolve. From what I can find, *son*, *sen*, and *søn* share the [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) root *sunuz*.

Both forms mean "son of Anders" (or "son of Andrew"). I would not be surprised to learn that any immigrants from Scandinavia to Britain anglicised their surname to better fit in, or immigrants from Britain to Scandinavia did the reverse.

As a bit of trivia, in addition to the literal use as "son of Andrew," some of the use of the name *Anderson* (also *fitz Andrew* and *MacGhilleAndrais*) in Scotland comes from St. Andrew being the patron saint of Scotland.

Comment: Perhaps to somewhat expand on this, -son is the form in modern Swedish and Icelandic, whilst Danish and Norwegian have -sen.